Custom button or menu entry for toggle of: File Status Auto-Detection
For some log files the "File Status Auto-Detection" is annyoing. For other (log) files, it is great.
Is there a way to provide the option "File Status Auto-Detection" faster/easier than opening the settings dialog?
Ideas:

Custom context menu entry (via default npp contextMenu.xml)

failed in adding a combobox style entry


Custom button in toolbar (via Plugin "Customize Toolbar")

failed in creating a working button


Hotkey

found no matching option


Macro

tried to record a macro while modifying the setting
but it does not record anything



Any ideas?

You might ask on the Notepad forum. If they do not have an answer then you might request the developer to add such a function.
